# How to use multiple index directory in hibernate-search?

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I use hibernate-search. I want that each user can see only theirself index and use it for searching and can't use index of other users. How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one index per indexed class (class hierarchy) and there is no Lucene index sharding. The Lucene way of solving your problem is using a filter which will filter away all results which don't belong to a certain user. Check the *SecurityFilter* example of the Hibernate Search online docs.